# discord.py - Runtime Command (Help)

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make an command so when someone does `#runtime` it shows how much time the bot has been active. So far everything works, but the problem is that the `while True:` part is blocking the execution of the command. Anyone could help me?

**CODE:**

```
import os
import discord
import asyncio
import chalk
import time
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.utils import get

print("DONE LOADING!\n")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='#')

client = discord.Client()

num1 = 0

num2 = 0

num3 = 0

num4 = 0

while True:
    num1 = num1+1
    if num1 == 60:
        num1 = 0
        num2 = num2+1
    if num2 == 60:
        num2 = 0
        num3 = num3+1
    if num3 == 24:
        num3 = 0
        num4 = num4+1
    time.sleep(1)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def runtime(ctx):
    await bot.say("Running for {}d {}h {}m {}s".format(num4, num3, num2, num1))
```

Comment: Replace `time.sleep(1)` with `await asyncio.sleep(1)`

Comment: You'll also have to place it in a coroutine, such as the [background task example bot](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/background_task.py) shows

Comment: An even better solution would be to capture the current time when the bot starts up, and then subtract that from the current time when the command is invoked.  the difference will be the time the bot has been up.

Comment: help needs `message` arg but I added it

`async def task(message):
    num1 = 0
    num2 = 0
    num3 = 0
    num4 = 0
    while not client.is_closed:
        num1 = num1+1
        if num1 == 60:
            num1 = 0
            num2 = num2+1
        if num2 == 60:
            num2 = 0
            num3 = num3+1
        if num3 == 24:
            num3 = 0
            num4 = num4+1
        print ("Running for {}d {}h {}m {}s".format(num4, num3, num2, num1))
        if "#runtime" in message.content:
            await bot.say("{}:{}:{}:{}".format(num4, num3, num2, num1))`

Comment: removed `asyncio.sleep(1)` becouse where was no space in the comment

Comment: I have no idea what's supposed to be going on in that code.  You can't put long code in comments, because they don't preserve indentation or line breaks.  Why would your task need a `message`? It starts before you receive any messages.

Comment: becouse it works inside the `background_task` but not outside. For example, in the code (background task) its counting the seconds but in `@bot.command (etc,etc)` it dosent show the numbers and said that num1,2,3,4 is not defined

Comment: Because those are local to the `task` coroutine. If you want them available in other scopes you need to use `global`

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easy way to do this is to capture the `datetime` when the bot comes up, and use that to calculate the elapsed time on demand.

```
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def runtime(ctx):
    now = datetime.utcnow()
    elapsed = now - starttime
    seconds = elapsed.seconds
    minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    await bot.say("Running for {}d {}h {}m {}s".format(elapsed.days, hours, minutes, seconds))

starttime = datetime.utcnow()
bot.run("...")
```